# mysql acusando erro ao tentar inserir um timestamp

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, plpgsql

Estou tentando passar um timestamp por parametro para uma function, porém acabo recebendo um erro de

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type time: "10"
```

o trecho onde eu passo é:

```
select agendar('2010-01-01 10:00:01')
```

o trecho que recebe é:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agendar(dia timestamp) returns bool as $$
declare

-- aqui eu declaro as variaveis....
begin
-- aqui o meu codigo
end
$$ language plpgsql
```

Comment: Qual o corpo da função completo? Sugiro remover a tag mysql se é uma função para postgresql.

Comment: O corpo continha algumas operações, o erro aparecia toda hora, então apaguei tudo e soltei um return true; e o erro continuou

Comment: @RenanBicudoFerrari Se você executa "select current_timestamp;" está sendo exibido o conteúdo semelhante ao formato de como está passando o parâmetro? Verifique também se ao executar "show datestyle;" está com o padrão que é "ISO, DMY"